# CSS, no javaScript, a list item is losing its line-height

Tags: css, list, hyperlink, tooltip

I've worked around a tooltip that appears in the same line where the link is located and it seems working well, best sying halfway. This tooltip is being used in a list, so it's in the same li where the link appears. The problem occurs in the next li, where the line-height seems to have been lost.

If someone could help me with this, here is the page I'm working in:
https:www.fredericopeter.com.br/playground

The damage is easily visible at the sidebar on the right side of the page.

The html code:

```
            <ul style="margin: 2px 0 10px 20px;">
                <li><a href="http://www.fredericopeter.com.br/">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.fredericopeter.com.br/blog/">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.fredericopeter.com.br/musicblog/">Música</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.fredericopeter.com.br/video/">Video</a></li>
                <li class="actual sidebar-tooltip"><a href="https://www.fredericopeter.com.br/playground/" onclick="return false;">Playground</a><span class="txt">◄ Você está aqui</span></li>
                <li style="clear: right;"><a href="http://www.fredericopeter.com.br/startpage/">Startpage</a> [<a href="http://www.fredericopeter.com.br/startpage/sobre/"> ? </a>]</li>
            </ul>
```

The css code (tooltip):

```
            a.sidebar-tooltip:hover {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            a.sidebar-tooltip span {
                z-index: 10;
                display: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin-top: 0;
                margin-left: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: right;
                color: #3cbfc7;
                background: transparent;
            }
            a.sidebar-tooltip:hover span {
                display: inline;
                position: absolute;
                border: 0;
                background: transparent;
            }
            .sidebar-tooltip {
                width: 109px;
                height: 10px;
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                border: 0;
                background: transparent;
            }
            .sidebar-tooltip:hover .txt {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .sidebar-tooltip .txt {
                margin-left: 3px;
                color: #0a0;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1000;
                background: transparent;
            }
            .sidebar-tooltip .txt:before {
                width: 0;
                padding: 0;
                position: absolute;
                content: '';
            }
```

Comment: Put the code in your question please.

Comment: I apologize, here is the link to the page: [link](https://www.fredericopeter.com.br/playground)

Comment: No links to a page, the question must contain the faulty code.

Comment: Ok, the css code: [link](https://www.fredericopeter.com.br/wp-content/themes/default/style.css). The ul li can be found at line 131 and the tooltip at line 362.

Comment: You can (and should) put the css in your question. Most people won't follow any links provided in questions. Besides that, the targets of links can change over time and it would be bad for future reference, if the faulty css would not be available anymore.

Comment: I apologize.
The html of the page: [link](https://www.fredericopeter.com.br/playground.html)
The css of the page: [link](https://www.fredericopeter.com.br/playground.css)

Comment: @Fredi You have been asked like 5 times to NOT put a link but to put your code DIRECTLY in your question above, and you keep replying with links

Comment: Sorry. Let's see:

Comment: I have forced the damaged nexr li to have a margin-top. It's not the solution, while i'm using em units in the css. Hope ther's a cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `.sidebar-tooltip` class and remove the height. I saw height is set 10px.

Comment: Hey, you've got it! So simple. Thank you very much.